# Bounding quantities that appear after using the residue theorem

Tags: calculus, residue-calculus

for an exercise using the residue theorem I need to prove that this term

$$\left|\dfrac{e^{R+it}-e^{-R-it}}{\left(e^{R+it}+e^{-R-it}\right)^2}\right|$$

tends to zero as $R\to\infty$. It's clear that somehow this quantity evolves as $e^{-R}$, but I don't know how to continue when at the end I have something of the form

$$\dfrac{1}{e^{R}|e^{2it}+e^{-4R}e^{-2it}+2e^{-2R}|}.$$

(I don't know if this is even correct.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $R>0$, we have $|e^{R+it}-e^{-R-it}|\leq e^R+1$ and:
$$ |e^{R+it}+e^{-R-it}|> e^{R}-1, $$
hence you only need to show that as long as $R\to +\infty$,
$$ \frac{e^R+1}{(e^R-1)^2}\to 0$$
that is quite trivial.

Comment: How do you prove $|e^{R+it}+e^{-R-it}|> e^{R}-1$? I could prove the first inequality, but I'm so bad in these things..

Comment: @Marc: it is the triangle inequality: $$\| a + b\|\geq \|a\|-\|b\|$$ together with the fact that $e^{-R}<1$ for any $R>0$.

Comment: Oh, now I see, quite easy after all, damn! Thank you! :)